# keyboard navigation in the Bootstrap dropdown-menu

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

As you know using Boostrap drop-down components you are not able to select an element by pressing the Keyboard Letter.
So i was using the following code which use a directive

```
myApp.directive('keyLetterPressed', function ($timeout) {
   return function (scope, element, attrs) {
    element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {

            var target = $(event.target);
            $(target).trigger('focus');

    });
   };
});
```

but this is not complete, actually is not working, just you can tell me 
how do i go to the element which have the same letter of the list ?
Also i have to put this directive in the Ul element ?
Because actually I am using it on the `li`

```
<li ng-repeat="v in values" keyLetterPressed>{{v.name}}</li>
```

Comment: [Here's a plunk to get people started](http://plnkr.co/edit/uCJQ3Ur5IVPqGK32TJVH?p=preview)

Comment: thank you very much man, i was working on this http://jsfiddle.net/QaVLm/52/ but i guess your is better

Comment: Either one is appreciated to help share code more quickly.  Have you looked into [`ng-keydown`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeydown)?  In either case, you might need to scope the listener at a higher level to catch the event as it bubbles up.  Also, how many items do you have in your menu? It seems like you're trying to get some `<select>` functionality.  You might want to checkout [ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select).

Comment: Hi KyleMit, i saw the project but it is very complicated i'm looking for something more simple also in my project is requested to don't use libraries.

Comment: KyleMit scope at more higher level means at document level?

Comment: i m  arrived to a nearest point https://jsfiddle.net/QaVLm/99/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another answer is this, adding the directive to the ul element

```
 app.directive('booststrapDropdown',
 function () {
  return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, element, attr) {
          console.log('linked');
          element.parent().bind('keypress', function (e) {
              children = element.children();
              children.removeClass("active");
              for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                  var letter = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
                  var charat = children[i].textContent.replace(/\s+/, '').charAt(0);
                  if (charat === letter) {
                      children[i].className += " active";
                      element[0].scrollTop = children[i].offsetTop;
                  }
              }
          });
      }
  };
  });



  <div class="btn-group" dropdown>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" 
            dropdown-toggle>
      Button dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul booststrap-dropdown class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu" role="menu" >
      <li ng-repeat="v in values">
        <a href="#">{{v.name}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be an a partial answer as you can see it worked just need a little adjustments.

Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QaVLm/112/)

Here is the code :

```
    myApp.directive('keypressEvents',

    function ($document, $rootScope) {
    return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {
        console.log('linked');
        $document.bind('keypress', function (e) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('keypress', e,  String.fromCharCode(e.which)); 
        var letter = String.fromCharCode(e.which);

        var target = e.target;

        var charat = element[0].textContent.charAt(0);

        if(charat === letter){ 
                element.addClass("red");
        }
        });
    }
}
});
```

Up there is the directive used, it simply is bound on the keypressed
and in the end set the class for the element found with the same first letter
just I need to set the focus on this and not just change the class

```
  <div class="dropup">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
   Dropup
   <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
        <li keypress-events><a href="#">action</a></li> 
       <li keypress-events><a href="#">something else here</a></li> 
     </ul>
   </div>
```

I have bound the directive on the `li` elements.
(rootscope and brodcast message was needed just for debugging)